# Kubeflow pipeline on AWS/On-prem currently feasible?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, argo-workflows

I’m testing kubeflow pipeline and would like to use it on AWS/On-prem but I saw the below comment on the documentation. Should I wait using it with AWS/on-prem?

> Due to kubeflow/pipelines#345 and kubeflow/pipelines#337, Kubeflow Pipelines depends on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) services and some of the functionality is currently not supported by non-GKE clusters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to wait.  See the status update on the issues and acitivity on [kubeflow/pipelines#1131](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/1131) to enable the support on AWS. Similar work is in progress for supporting on-prem as well.

Answer (score 0):

On-prem is definitely possible.
KFP is not tied to GCP and can work even on Windows tables.

AWS support is mostly provided by the community, but most of the issues have been fixed. There are samples that show demonstrate KFP on AWS and there are multiple AWS and Sagemaker components created by people form AWS. https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/091316b8bf3790e14e2418843ff67a3072cfadc0/samples/contrib/aws-samples/titanic-survival-prediction/titanic-survival-prediction.py